# Error while importing the Binding FIles

Tags: c#, biztalk, host, biztalk-orchestrations

For a test application I am importing binding files to my BTS console but I am getting the error that **Trust level="untrusted" issue**. When I checked this I found that My host has been created with `trust level= true` but the binding that I got from the machine, there *trust level was false*. so I am not able to import it.

I am also not able to change the trust level of my host because some other applications are running on it.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the bindings file, on the appropriate <ReceiveHandler> and/or <SendHandler> elements, set HostTrusted="true".

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution requires that the Host Trusted option be the right value, true or false, doesn't really matter, across all environments.

So, at some point, you really should figure out exactly what it should be (probably false since if it had to be true, you would know exactly why) and change the setting on the incorrect Host.

As an immediate workaround, sure, just change the flag in the binding file, but again, that's not the right way to address this.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have seen this kind of error where it actually helped to remove the following folder completely:

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\BizTalk Server\Deployment
```

It contains binding files from all deployments and sometimes BizTalk mix up which binding file is being used.